# How to find max and min within sequence of values in a column in R?

Tags: r

This problem might be trivial but I am finding it difficult to solve it. Please guide me.

## Data

Following is sample data:

```
structure(list(Vehicle.ID2 = c("39-25", "39-25", "39-25", "39-25", 
"39-25", "39-25", "39-25", "39-25", "39-25", "39-25", "39-25", 
"39-25", "39-25", "39-25", "39-25", "39-25", "39-25", "39-25", 
"39-25", "39-25", "39-25", "39-25", "39-25", "39-25", "39-25", 
"39-25", "39-25", "39-25", "39-25", "39-25", "39-25", "39-25", 
"39-25", "39-25", "39-25", "39-25", "39-25", "39-25", "39-25"
), OC_DV = c(".", ".", ".", ".", ".", "CLDV", ".", ".", ".", 
".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", "OPDV", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", 
".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", 
".", "CLDV", ".", ".", "."), frspacing = c(35.83373, 35.75742, 
35.70391, 35.67694, 35.67792, 35.70669, 35.7619, 35.84096, 35.93962, 
36.05109, 36.16704, 36.28056, 36.3861, 36.47762, 36.5485, 36.59359, 
36.61402, 36.61791, 36.61383, 36.60651, 36.59694, 36.58372, 36.56525, 
36.54044, 36.50771, 36.46458, 36.40831, 36.33713, 36.25086, 36.15089, 
36.04004, 35.92236, 35.80322, 35.68935, 35.58883, 35.51032, 35.4618, 
35.4492, 35.47479)), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, 
-39L), .Names = c("Vehicle.ID2", "OC_DV", "frspacing"))
```

## What I want to do

I want to find the max and min of set of values in `frspacing` between the labels `CLDV` and `OPDV` in the column `OC_DV`. Then I want to find their difference.

## Desired Output

Following are max and mins:

```
  Group      Max    Min
1 CLDV-OPDV 36.54   35.70
2 OPDV-CLDV 36.62   35.59
```

Following are the absolute differences (max of 1st grp - min of 2nd group AND vice versa):

```
1 0.95
2 0.92
```

I don't have any code to show what I tried because honestly I don't know how to approach this problem. Obviously simple `max` or `min` by column won't work. I am using `dplyr` and didn't find anything relevant.

Comment: Could you provide clarification for the second part of your question? For example, if you have more than two groups in your outcome df and you want to get the difference for row 1, are you finding the min of the min of every other row, or just the min of the 2nd row?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
 library(zoo) # for na.locf
 library(dplyr)

 df[df=="."] = NA
 df$group = paste((na.locf(df$OC_DV, na.rm = FALSE)), lead(na.locf(df$OC_DV, na.rm = FALSE, fromLast = TRUE)), sep = "-")

 df %>% group_by(group) %>% 
   summarise(Max = max(frspacing), Min = min(frspacing)) %>% 
   filter(!grepl("NA",group ))

Source: local data frame [2 x 3]

      group      Max      Min
      (chr)    (dbl)    (dbl)
1 CLDV-OPDV 36.54850 35.70669
2 OPDV-CLDV 36.61791 35.58883
```

With multiple values I would count the changes und use it as another grouping variable:
(I duplicated the data in this example)

```
df$group2 = NA
df$group2[which(df$group != lag(df$group))] = 1:length(which(df$group != lag(df$group)))
df$group2 = na.locf(df$group2, na.rm = FALSE)

df %>% group_by(group, group2) %>% 
  summarise(Max = max(frspacing), Min = min(frspacing)) %>% 
   filter(!grepl("NA",group ))

Source: local data frame [5 x 4]
Groups: group [3]

      group group2      Max      Min
      (chr)  (int)    (dbl)    (dbl)
1 CLDV-CLDV      3 38.09082 34.30454
2 CLDV-OPDV      1 36.54850 35.70669
3 CLDV-OPDV      4 38.90356 34.08951
4 OPDV-CLDV      2 36.61791 35.58883
5 OPDV-CLDV      5 38.18983 34.27874
```

But if the combination of `OC_DV` is distinct in every `Vehicle.ID2` you can simply paste the ID in group...

Comment: Thanks! I tried this on full data and it works fine. Only 1 more thing, if there are multiple `CLDV-OPDV` and `OPDV-CLDV` groups, how can I find `max` and `min` for each? I tried adding `frspacing` in your `paste` command but then each row is a separate group.

Comment: You could paste the `Vehicle.ID2` instead of `frspacing` if the values are distinct. If that's not the case see my update.

Comment: @Cabana, I was not able to replicate your bottom example, could you provide code for how you made the `df`? You say that you duplicated the data in the example, however, `max(df$frspacing = 36.62` and `min(df$frspacing=35.4492` while you return `38.9` and `34.27`, both of which are out of the range of the original `df`. Thanks, nice answer! +1

Comment: @Cabana, I'm guessing you did something like `df <- rbind(df, df)` and then `df$frspacing[40:78] <- runif(39, 34, 39)`.

Comment: @Cabana, Thanks a lot!

Comment: @Joseph Yes, I bound them together and used rnorm on the second half. Sorry should have posted it.

Answer (score 1):

```
d <- your_dput
# Build your subsetted dataframes
e <- d[grep("CLDV", d$OC_DV)[1]: grep("OPDV", d$OC_DV),]
f <- d[(grep("OPDV", d$OC_DV): grep("CLDV", d$OC_DV)[2]),]
# Make the diff() calls
diff(c(max(e$frspacing), min(f$frspacing)))
diff(c(max(f$frspacing), min(e$frspacing)))
```

My values are not quiet the same as yours, you can adjust the grep values manually depending on how you want to handle boundary inclusion/exclusion.

Comment: Thank for your answer. What if I don't know beforehand how many `OPDV`s and `CLDV`s I have in `OC_DV`?

Comment: Just guessing but are those "open" and "close" indicators? If so are they always paired?

Comment: Yes, they are 'open' and 'close' indicators in context of 'car-following' process. Sometimes they are paired, sometimes not. `CLDV` can appear before `OPDV` or after it. For each unique `Vehicle.ID2` they appear differently. I reproduced only a small portion of data.

Comment: I like @Cabana 's zoo::na.locf() solution better than my idea

Answer (score 1):

Below is a base R solution:

```
MaxMinSeq <- function(df) {
    myInd <- which(df$OC_DV != ".")
    myVals <- df$frspacing
    myTitles <- df$OC_DV[myInd]
    myLen <- length(myInd)-1L
    NewDf <- as.data.frame(t(sapply(1:myLen, function(x) {
               list(Group = paste(c(myTitles[x],"-",myTitles[x+1L]), collapse = ""),
                   Max = max(myVals[myInd[x]:(myInd[x+1L]-1L)]),
                   Min = min(myVals[myInd[x]:(myInd[x+1L]-1L)]))})))
    for (i in 1:3) {NewDf[,i] <- unlist(NewDf[,i])}
    NewDf
}

df2 <- MaxMinSeq(df)
df2
      Group      Max      Min
1 CLDV-OPDV 36.54850 35.70669
2 OPDV-CLDV 36.61791 35.58883
```

This is a good bit faster than the `dplyr` solution posted above. Observe:

```
TestDplyr <- function(df) {
    df[df=="."] <- NA
    df$group <- paste((na.locf(df$OC_DV, na.rm = FALSE)), lead(na.locf(df$OC_DV, na.rm = FALSE, fromLast = TRUE)), sep = "-")

    df$group2 <- NA
    df$group2[which(df$group != lag(df$group))] <- 1:length(which(df$group != lag(df$group)))
    df$group2 <- na.locf(df$group2, na.rm = FALSE)

    df %>% group_by(group, group2) %>% 
        summarise(Max = max(frspacing), Min = min(frspacing)) %>% 
        filter(!grepl("NA",group ))
}

microbenchmark(Joseph = MaxMinSeq(df), Cabana = TestDplyr(df))
Unit: microseconds
expr      min        lq      mean    median       uq      max neval
Joseph  338.671  377.6695  405.0257  405.9945  429.188  496.718   100
Cabana 2622.336 2698.2810 2890.5430 2765.6045 2977.427 7772.180   100
```

Here is a really big example:

```
myDfs <- lapply(1:10000, function(x) df)
bigDf <- do.call(rbind, myDfs)
bigDf$frspacing[40:nrow(bigDf)] <- runif((nrow(bigDf)-39), 10, 100)

a <- MaxMinSeq(bigDf)
b <- TestDplyr(bigDf)
b <- b[order(b$group2),]

identical(a$Max, b$Max)
[1] TRUE
identical(a$Min, b$Min)
[1] TRUE

system.time(TestDplyr(bigDf))
 user  system elapsed 
 1.54    0.00    1.54 
system.time(MaxMinSeq(bigDf))
 user  system elapsed 
  0.3     0.0     0.3
```

As for the second part of the question, I'm not sure how general the OP would like the answer to be especially when there are more than two different final pairings. For example does the OP want to find the max of one row and compare that to the min of the min of all rows, or do we simply compare neighbors? The function below takes the first approach (i.e. the general approach).

```
GetDiff <- function(df) {
    df2 <- cbind(df, t(sapply(1:nrow(df), function(x) {
                        c(rowMin = min(df[x,2:3]),
                          rowMax = max(df[x,2:3]))})))
    myRows <- 1:nrow(df)
    sapply(myRows, function(x) df2$rowMax[x] - min(df2$rowMin[-x]))
}

GetDiff(df2)   ## df2 comes from above
[1] 0.95967 0.91122
```